# generate Excel from jQuery Datatable buttons were in disabled state

Tags: datatables

I was trying to implement generate Excel from jQuery datatable. The icons in the flash video were in disabled state except print option. What could be the issue?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">  

@import "/public/stylesheets/TableTools.css";

    .dataTables_info { padding-top: 0; }
    .dataTables_paginate { padding-top: 0; }
    .css_right { float: right; }
    #example_wrapper .fg-toolbar { font-size: 0.8em }
    #theme_links span { float: left; padding: 2px 10px; }

</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "/public/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
                },
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
}
            );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the datatables and TableTools it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused by the fact that the flash component is not loaded correctly. You should set the path manually like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
} );
```

Comment: still it is disabled. I have added the code Please check the question

Comment: only print button is enabled i used "aButtons": [ "copy", "print" ] option but it is showing all the controls. is there any path problem